# Webpack-ImageMinimizerPlugin select files

Tags: webpack, imagemin, imagemin-webp

How to include or exclude files from the compression process?

I'm using the ImageMinimizerPlugin together with the CopyPlugin as follows:

ImageMinimizerPlugin configuration:

```
const imgMinParams = {
  include: PATHS.src + '/assets/images/include/these/files/',
  generator: [
    {
      type: 'asset',
      preset: 'webp',
      implementation: ImageMinimizerPlugin.sharpGenerate,
      options: {
        encodeOptions: {
          webp: {
            quality: 6,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

Optimization:

```
optimization: {
minimize: true,
minimizer: [
  ...
  new ImageMinimizerPlugin(imgMinParams),
],
},
```

Copyplugin configuration:

```
const copyPluginParams = {
  patterns: [
    {
      from: PATHS.src + '/assets/images/include/these/files/*.*',
      to: PATHS.src + '/assets/images/compressed/[name].webp',
    },
    {
      from: PATHS.src + '/assets/images/do/not/include/these/fi/*.*',
      to: PATHS.src + '/assets/images/uncompressed/[name][ext]',
    },
  ]
```

Plugins:

```
plugins: [
...
new CopyPlugin(copyPluginParams),
],
```